# Why is save attachment in path giving "error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: An error has occurred." number -2700"?" in Outlook 2016?

Tags: outlook, applescript, email-attachments

`save f` in `saveAsName` fails all the times.

`f` is the attachment, `saveAsName` is the path with file name.

The error from `Message tab` is:

> save attachment 1 of incoming message id 442 in "/Users/path/Att-1-1 image001.jpg"
>           --> error number -2700

applescript Result tab from bottom:

> error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: An error has occurred." number -2700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because save ... in ... takes a *file* reference, not a string. So try

```
save f in POSIX file saveAsName
```

Comment: Thank you. I am away right now for the weekend. I shall try and get back to you by tomorrow. I apologize for the delayed reply.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It saved my day.